# Script para recargar página con pausa

Tags: php, jquery, script

Estoy desarrollando una web y necesito que la página me actualice cada 5 segundos, pero que pueda pausar la actualización en cualquier momento. Tengo un botón para ello.

He desarrollado el siguiente script, pero no funciona. Cuando pulso el botón la variable cambia a 2 y el valor del botón a "Activar", por lo que no deberia realizar el setTimeout, pero la web se actualiza igualmente.

¿Que puede estar pasando? Gracias de antemano!

```
<script>
 //Cuando la página esté cargada completamente
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var estado = 1;   
     alert(estado);
   //Cada 10 segundos (10000 milisegundos) se ejecutará la función refrescar    
   $('.botonactivar').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr("value") == "Parar"){
           $(this).val("Activar");
           estado = 2;  
           alert(estado);
       }else{
           $(this).val("Parar");     
           estado = 1;   
           alert(estado); 
       }
   });

   if(estado == 1){
       setTimeout(refrescar, 5000); 
   }
 });

 function refrescar(){
   //Actualiza la página
   location.reload();
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El estado inicial es `1` por lo que está entrando al segundo bloque `if` y creando un timeout, no importa si haces click y cambias el estado a `2`, el timeout todavía existe.

Para solucionarlo, debes guardar el `id` que identifica al timeout y "limpiarlo" al desactivar la actualización

```js
var timeoutID = null;
$('.botonactivar').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr("value") == "Parar"){
           $(this).val("Activar");
           estado = 2;  
           alert(estado);
       }else{
           $(this).val("Parar");     
           estado = 1;   
           alert(estado); 
       }
   });

   if(estado == 1){
       timeoutID = setTimeout(refrescar, 5000); 
   } else {
       clearTimeout(timeoutID);
       timeoutID = null;
   }
```

Algunos consejos no solicitados:

- usa un `boolean` para manejar el estado dado que solo tienes 2 estados
- en lugar de configurar la condición basada en el texto del botón, utiliza el estado
- `alert` bloquea la ejecución de la página, creo que es mejor usar `console.log`
- Ambos bloques `if` están "haciendo lo mismo", puedes unificarlos

**Actualización**
Una descripción de cómo está funcionando el código:

- se setea la variable `timeoutID` con un valor de nulo
- se agrega un listener a `.botonactivar` cuando se hace click
- Verifica el valor de `estado` y crea un timeout si el valor es `1` o basado en el nuevo código `true`
- Este último paso solo lo hace una vez

Para que esa condición la compruebe cada vez que se hace click en el botón, se debe mover el código dentro de `click`, o llamar a una función que compruebe el estado, aquí va el código completo:

```html
<script>
  //Cuando la página esté cargada completamente
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var timeoutID = null;
    var estado = true;

    function comprobarEstado() {
      if(estado == true){
        console.log("activo");
        timeoutID = setTimeout(refrescar, 5000);             
      } else {
        console.log("desactivo");
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = null;
      } 
    }
        $('.botonactivar').click(function() {
            if(estado){
              $(this).val("Activar");
              estado = false;
            } else {
              $(this).val("Parar");
              estado = true;
            }
          comprobarEstado();
        });

    comprobarEstado();

    function refrescar(){
        //Actualiza la página
        location.reload();
  }    
 });  
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación. Voy a probarlo a ver si lo conseguimos. Poco a poco vamos mejorando! :)

Comment: Ya entiendo el funcionamiento y además funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, no solo has resuelto mi problema si no que tambien me has enseñado. Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar la función que recarga la pagina dentro de la condición inicial, así por ejemplo:

```
<script>
//Cuando la página esté cargada completamente
$(document).ready(function(){
   var estado = 1;   
   alert(estado);
   //Cada 10 segundos (10000 milisegundos) se ejecutará la función refrescar    
   $('.botonactivar').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr("value") == "Parar"){
           $(this).val("Activar");
           estado = 2;  
           alert(estado);
       }else{
           $(this).val("Parar");     
           estado = 1;   
           alert(estado);
           setTimeout(refrescar, 5000);
    }
  });
  function refrescar(){
     //Actualiza la página
     location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Steven, gracias por tu aporte! el "problema es que si agrego la funcion a la condición inicial solo me refresca la página cuando pulso el botón. Necesito que la página se refresque todo el tiempo, y solo se pause cuando le de al botón

Answer (score 0):

he seguido la idea de "Aguardientico" (gracias!). La página actualiza desde el principio cada 5 segundos, pero no me para la actualización cuando pulso en parar. Solo cambia el texto del botón.

Este es el código actualizado:

```
<script>
  //Cuando la página esté cargada completamente
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var timeoutID = null;
    var estado = true;
        $('.botonactivar').click(function() {
            if($(this).attr("value") == "Parar"){
                $(this).val("Activar");
                estado = false;  
            }else{
                $(this).val("Parar");     
                estado = true;   
            }
        });

        if(estado == true){
            console.log("activo");
            timeoutID = setTimeout(refrescar, 5000);             
        } else {
            console.log("desactivo");
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            timeoutID = null;
        } 

    function refrescar(){
        //Actualiza la página
        location.reload();
  }    
 });  
</script>
```

En la consola solo aparece "activo", nunca llega a "desactivo". No llego a entender que ocurre, ya que al pulsar el botón el estado es igual a false y deberia dejar de realizar el timeout. Gracias!

Comment: Recuerda que, si una respuesta te ayudó, puedes marcarla como aceptada (con el tick junto a los votos de la respuesta). Así otros sabrán cómo se resuelve esa pregunta! :)

Comment: @jesus actualicé la respuesta con una explicación de lo que está pasando y cómo resolverlo